# Azure AKS Scale out

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-aks, azure-vm-scale-set

I have AKS with 03 nodes, I tried to manually scale out from 3 to 4 nodes. Scale up was fine.
After ~ 20 minutes , all 04 Node are in NotReady Service, all kube-system services is not Ready status.

```
NAME STATUS ROLES AGE VERSION
aks-agentpool-40760006-vmss000000 Ready agent 16m v1.18.14
aks-agentpool-40760006-vmss000001 Ready agent 17m v1.18.14
aks-agentpool-40760006-vmss000002 Ready agent 16m v1.18.14
aks-agentpool-40760006-vmss000003 Ready agent 11m v1.18.14

NAME STATUS ROLES AGE VERSION
aks-agentpool-40760006-vmss000000 NotReady agent 23m v1.18.14
aks-agentpool-40760006-vmss000002 NotReady agent 24m v1.18.14
aks-agentpool-40760006-vmss000003 NotReady agent 19m v1.18.14

k get po -n kube-system
NAME                                  READY   STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-748cdb7bf4-7frq2              0/1     Pending       0          10m
coredns-748cdb7bf4-vg5nn              0/1     Pending       0          10m
coredns-748cdb7bf4-wrhxs              1/1     Terminating   0          28m
coredns-autoscaler-868b684fd4-2gb8f   0/1     Pending       0          10m
kube-proxy-p6wmv                      1/1     Running       0          28m
kube-proxy-sksz6                      1/1     Running       0          23m
kube-proxy-vpb2g                      1/1     Running       0          28m
metrics-server-58fdc875d5-sbckj       0/1     Pending       0          10m
tunnelfront-5d74798f6b-w6rvn          0/1     Pending       0          10m
```

The node logs shows that:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                   Age                   From              Message
  ----     ------                   ----                  ----              -------
  Normal   Starting                 25m                   kubelet           Starting kubelet.
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientMemory  25m (x2 over 25m)     kubelet           Node aks-agentpool-40760006-vmss000000 status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
  Normal   NodeHasNoDiskPressure    25m (x2 over 25m)     kubelet           Node aks-agentpool-40760006-vmss000000 status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientPID     25m (x2 over 25m)     kubelet           Node aks-agentpool-40760006-vmss000000 status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID
  Normal   NodeAllocatableEnforced  25m                   kubelet           Updated Node Allocatable limit across pods
  Normal   Starting                 25m                   kube-proxy        Starting kube-proxy.
  Normal   NodeReady                24m                   kubelet           Node aks-agentpool-40760006-vmss000000 status is now: NodeReady
  Warning  FailedToCreateRoute      5m5s                  route_controller  Could not create route e496c1aa-be11-412b-b820-178d83b42f29 10.244.2.0/24 for node aks-agentpool-40760006-vmss000000 after 50.264754ms: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedToCreateRoute      4m55s                 route_controller  Could not create route e496c1aa-be11-412b-b820-178d83b42f29 10.244.2.0/24 for node aks-agentpool-40760006-vmss000000 after 45.945658ms: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedToCreateRoute      4m45s                 route_controller  Could not create route e496c1aa-be11-412b-b820-178d83b42f29 10.244.2.0/24 for node aks-agentpool-40760006-vmss000000 after 46.180158ms: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedToCreateRoute      4m35s                 route_controller  Could not create route e496c1aa-be11-412b-b820-178d83b42f29 10.244.2.0/24 for node aks-agentpool-40760006-vmss000000 after 46.550858ms: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedToCreateRoute      4m25s                 route_controller  Could not create route e496c1aa-be11-412b-b820-178d83b42f29 10.244.2.0/24 for node aks-agentpool-40760006-vmss000000 after 44.74355ms: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedToCreateRoute      4m15s                 route_controller  Could not create route e496c1aa-be11-412b-b820-178d83b42f29 10.244.2.0/24 for node aks-agentpool-40760006-vmss000000 after 42.428456ms: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedToCreateRoute      4m5s                  route_controller  Could not create route e496c1aa-be11-412b-b820-178d83b42f29 10.244.2.0/24 for node aks-agentpool-40760006-vmss000000 after 41.664858ms: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedToCreateRoute      3m55s                 route_controller  Could not create route e496c1aa-be11-412b-b820-178d83b42f29 10.244.2.0/24 for node aks-agentpool-40760006-vmss000000 after 48.456954ms: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedToCreateRoute      3m45s                 route_controller  Could not create route e496c1aa-be11-412b-b820-178d83b42f29 10.244.2.0/24 for node aks-agentpool-40760006-vmss000000 after 38.611964ms: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedToCreateRoute      65s (x16 over 3m35s)  route_controller  (combined from similar events): Could not create route e496c1aa-be11-412b-b820-178d83b42f29 10.244.2.0/24 for node aks-agentpool-40760006-vmss000000 after 13.972487ms: timed out waiting for the condition
```

Comment: How is your AKS cluster configured? Are you using your own Kubenet or Azure CNI networking?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cluster autoscaler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-autoscaler) option to avoid  such situations in future.

> To keep up with application demands in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS),
> you may need to adjust the number of nodes that run your workloads.
> The cluster autoscaler component can watch for pods in your cluster
> that can't be scheduled because of resource constraints. When issues
> are detected, the number of nodes in a node pool is increased to meet
> the application demand. Nodes are also regularly checked for a lack of
> running pods, with the number of nodes then decreased as needed. This
> ability to automatically scale up or down the number of nodes in your
> AKS cluster lets you run an efficient, cost-effective cluster.

You can [Update an existing AKS cluster to enable the cluster autoscaler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-autoscaler#update-an-existing-aks-cluster-to-enable-the-cluster-autoscaler) in order to use your current resource group.

```
az aks update \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --name myAKSCluster \
  --enable-cluster-autoscaler \
  --min-count 1 \
  --max-count 3
```

Comment: In what way would the cluster autoscaler solve the OP's problem?

Comment: I think the point is to scale the cluster through the AKS resource rather than the underlying VMSS, if that is what the OP was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Seem it is OK now. I am lacking of the right to scale up node.